# A Promotion for the Community Promotion Ads

Tags: discussion, advertising

I have a [pending community promotion ad](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5801/community-promotion-ads-2018/6691#6691) that I believe deserves more attention — but I also think that we need more participation generally in the cause of creating community promotion ads.  As we approach the end of 2018, I'd like to draw everyone's attention to the ads and invite everyone to consider what issues with the site deserve promotion and create proposed ads.

BTW: I created the [advertising](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertising) tag because (a) it didn't exist and (b) the [community-ads](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag refers to it.

---

**Edit:**

*This question earned me the [Tumbleweed badge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed), which [I didn't think could be practically earned on this site](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5635/shouldnt-the-tumbleweed-badge-be-either-gold-or-burned).  My sincere thanks to everyone for completely ignoring this question.  Cheers!*

Comment: Not ignored, you got 6 votes.

Comment: @Vincent, huh... how do I see that?  (And why did I get the badge if there was activity?) Thanks.

Comment: You don't know? Just click on the 0 between the voting arrows. The badge simply says a 0 score.

Comment: @Vincent, Sonofagun!  I never knew.  Now I wonder why I received the badge.